# Simple PDF file attachment in PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm trying the simplest way to send an -email- with -an attached file- using PHP mailer.

I tried using this

```
   $mail ->addAttachment("path_to_pdf", "pdf_name);
```

but it does't work, since the "Mail is sent" but the "PDF file attachment" is not sent.

Please help me solve my problem, I want to attach a pdf file in the email I want to send to the receiver. Thanks!

Here are the files I used to send email w/file attachment.

the index.html

```
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="send_mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            To : <input type="text" name="mail_to"> <br/>
            Subject :   <input type="text" name="mail_sub">
           <br/>
             Message   <input type="text" name="mail_msg">
             <br/>
            File: <input type="file" name="file" >
            <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Email">

            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and

send_mail.php

```
      <?php

        $mailto = $_POST['mail_to'];
        $mailSub = $_POST['mail_sub'];
        $mailMsg = $_POST['mail_msg'];
       require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       $mail ->IsSmtp();
       $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
       $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
       $mail ->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
       $mail ->Port = 465; // or 587
       $mail ->IsHTML(true);
       $mail ->Username = "acc.ldevera@gmail.com";
       $mail ->Password = "accountsamplepassword";
       $mail ->SetFrom("acc.sample@gmail.com");
       $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
       $mail ->Body = $mailMsg;
       $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);
        $mail->AddAttachment('pdf_files/', 'reservation.pdf');


       if(!$mail->Send())
       {
           echo "Mail Not Sent";
       }
       else
       {
           echo "Mail Sent";
       }

    ?>
```

Please help me with my problem, Thanks!

Comment: If that's the real password you use, then kindly change it asap. Further clarify the exact issue and where you are facing it

Comment: Changing the password in question won't help as edit history can be seen. So, you would need to change your account password! Bummer :|

Comment: Hahahaha hello, is alright. The account was not a legit account, I used it for dummy testing :)

Comment: Thanks Nobody, you're very thoughtful :)

Comment: Though I'm no expert in PHP, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876228/php-mailer-attachments?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236259/send-files-with-phpmailer-before-uploading-them?rq=1)

Comment: This looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer. Update to [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/), and base your code on [the `send_file_upload` example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps). It doesn't help that you're not checking the return value from `addAttachment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line doesn't do what you'd expect

```
$mail->AddAttachment('pdf_files/', 'reservation.pdf');
```

it tries to find a file named 'pdf_files/' and wants to add it. however, as you might imagine now, this isn't a proper file name. The first argument of `AddAttachment` is the path of the file (that is the including the filename of the file), the second parameter is the filename, which is *shown* in the email, how the file is supposed to be called/named, so you can call it differently, without renaming the original file.

so the line above should probably read:

```
$mail->AddAttachment('pdf_files/reservation.pdf', 'reservation.pdf');
```

Comment: how about this?

Comment: $mail ->AddAttachment('pdf_files/' . $_POST['pdf_name'], 'reservation.pdf');

Comment: @LapizStone that sounds like a bad idea. you really would want to sanitize your input, because someone could post `"../../config.php"` or something and find out all your server passwords (or at least some database password), as soon as he finds the config file this way.